# How to delete all the data below the specific line of html by python3

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a html file in which the data contains more than 300 lines. I want to delete all the data below a specific line. For example, I want to delete all the data below the following lines. How?

```
<pre>
Page 5
```

If possible, keep the closing tags which is the last line of the html.

```
<hr></body></html>
```

I wrote the following code. But it deletes only the particular(Page 5) line. I want to delete all the lines below "Page 5". How?

```
f = open("4105.html","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("4105-modified.html","w")
for line in lines:
  if line!='''Page 5'''+"\n":
    f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop writing lines after you find `Page 5`:

```
with open('4105.html') as inf, open('4105-modified.html','w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write(line)
        if line == 'Page 5\n':
            break

    # if you want the last tags to remain
    outf.write('<hr></body></html>')
```

I'd consider using an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup, instead.

**Edit per comment (untested)**

```
with open('4105.html') as inf, open('4105-modified.html','w') as outf:
    lines = inf.readlines()
    idx = lines.index('Page 5\n')
    if idx != -1: # found it
        del lines[idx - 1] # delete line before
        del lines[idx:-1]  # delete all lines except last to keep trailing tags.
    outf.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Works fine. How can i remove the <pre> tag, just above the Page 5 but not the other <pre> tags?

Comment: @info-farmer Look into BeautifulSoup.  It parses the HTML and you can remove whatever sections you like; otherwise, see my edit.